java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo in case of PDF document only
ava.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=732713151, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/... flg=0x43 }} to activity {com.nxplayr.fsl/com.nareshchocha.filepickerlibrary.ui.activitys.DocumentFilePickerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5527)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5566)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:67)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.nareshchocha.filepickerlibrary.utilities.FileUtils.getDataColumn(FileUtils.kt:154)
    at com.nareshchocha.filepickerlibrary.utilities.FileUtils.getMediaDocumentPath(FileUtils.kt:96)
    at com.nareshchocha.filepickerlibrary.utilities.FileUtils.pathFromURI(FileUtils.kt:39)
    at com.nareshchocha.filepickerlibrary.utilities.FileUtils.getRealPath(FileUtils.kt:21)
    at com.nareshchocha.filepickerlibrary.ui.activitys.DocumentFilePickerActivity$selectFile$1.invoke(DocumentFilePickerActivity.kt:66)
    at com.nareshchocha.filepickerlibrary.ui.activitys.DocumentFilePickerActivity$selectFile$1.invoke(DocumentFilePickerActivity.kt:56)
    at com.nareshchocha.filepickerlibrary.picker.PickerUtils.selectFile$lambda$0(PickerUtils.kt:23)
    at com.nareshchocha.filepickerlibrary.picker.PickerUtils.$r8$lambda$5EjpwZuwUTQfOHixKEdyGZdAUG8(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.nareshchocha.filepickerlibrary.picker.PickerUtils$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onActivityResult(Unknown Source:2)
    at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.doDispatch(ActivityResultRegistry.kt:371)
    at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.dispatchResult(ActivityResultRegistry.kt:331)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onActivityResult(ComponentActivity.kt:786)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:152)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8943)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5520)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5566) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:67) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 

I'm using this library.
implementation "io.github.chochanaresh:filepicker:0.1.7"

Getting this exception only in case of PDF document. Image and video is working fine.
Anyone facing same issue?
Any solution ?

"Image and video is working fine" -- it is "working fine" only on the handful of scenarios you tried on the device you tested. It will not work in general, because a Uri is not a file, and you cannot reliably get a filesystem path for one. "any solution ?" -- stop using that library and use the Uri properly, using things like ContentResolver and DocumentFile.
